# Array field always stores the last value of the field into database

Tags: laravel-5

Help me working with array inputs on my project.
This is the form field:

```
<form action="" method="">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="scores[]">
    <input type="hidden" name="lesson_id[]" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="year_id" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="grade_id" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="clas_id" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="student_id" value="">
</form>
```

My Controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {

        foreach ($request->scores as $score)
        {
            $scr = new Assestment;
            $scr->year_id = $request->year_id;
            $scr->grade_id = $request->grade_id;
            $scr->clas_id = $request->clas_id;
            $scr->student_id = $request->student_id;
            foreach($request->lesson_id as $lesson)
            {
                $scr->lesson_id = $lesson;
            }
            $scr->score = $score;
            $scr->save();
        }

    }
```

My Model:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Assestment extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'assestments';

    protected $fillable = [
        'year_id', 'grade_id', 'clas_id', 'student_id', 'lesson_id', 'score',
    ];

    public function students()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Student');
    }

}
```

I would like to make the value of field "scores[]" and "lesson_id[]" as array so that they store multiple data to database.
But when I submit the form, the "lesson_id[]" always store the last value of the form. For example, the field "lesson_id[]" contains multiple values like "1, 2, 3 , 4", but the value stored into database is always "4 (the last value of the field)".

What should I do?

Comment: only last value is stored because you saved after foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

Only the last value is stored because you stored the data after foreach loop.
If you want to store the `socres[]` and `lesson_id[]` as an array in the same table, you can use `serialize()`

```
 $scr = new Assestment;
 $scr->year_id = $request->year_id;
 $scr->grade_id = $request->grade_id;
 $scr->clas_id = $request->clas_id;
 $scr->student_id = $request->student_id;
 $scr->lesson_id = serialize($request->lesson_id);
 $scr->score = serialize($request->$score);
 $scr->save();
```

To retreive each value, use `unserialize()`

Comment: it doesn work dude. all i want to do is just give scores based on the lessons. if there are 10 lessons, then there will be 10 text-fields containing the id of the lessons and 10 text-fields for the scores. but everytime i submit the form, the score stored into dabase is based on input, but the lesson_id[] always store the last id. for example:
{{Form::text('lesson_id[]', '1')}}
{{Form::text('lesson_id[]', '2')}}
{{Form::text('lesson_id[]', '5')}}
{{Form::text('lesson_id[]', '7')}}
{{Form::text('lesson_id[]', '12')}} the value stored into database is always "12". do you get what i mean?

Comment: why don't you save inside foreach loop?